# How to find date ranges in records with consecutive dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with data like so:

```
ID    StartDate    EndDate     EffectiveDate
--    ---------    -------     -------------
1     1/1/2009     12/31/2009    12/31/2009
1     7/1/2009     12/31/2009    7/1/2009
1     8/1/2009     12/31/2009    8/1/2009
2     1/1/2010     12/31/2010    12/31/2010
2     3/1/2010     12/31/2010    12/31/2010
```

I need a query that will format it like this, however:

```
ID    StartDate    EndDate     EffectiveDate
--    ---------    -------     -------------
1     1/1/2009     6/30/2009    null
1     7/1/2009     7/31/2009    7/1/2009
1     8/1/2009     12/31/2009   8/1/2009
2     1/1/2010     2/28/2010    null
2     3/1/2010     12/31/2010   12/31/2010
...
```

It's basically like a timeline with segmented "points", and each point is a new StartDate with an EndDate of the next point, and so on.

I've tried using a CTE, as well as the following query:

```
   SELECT t1.RfqItemOptionId, 
          t1.StartDate, 
          MIN(t2.EffectiveDate) EndDate,  
          t1.EffectiveDate EffectiveDate
     FROM @OptionPeriods t1 
LEFT JOIN @OptionPeriods t2 ON t1.RfqItemOptionId = t2.RfqItemOptionId
                           AND t1.EffectiveDate < t2.EffectiveDate
 GROUP BY t1.RfqItemOptionId, t1.StartDate, t1.EffectiveDate
```

Which is close...but no cigar :(

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;With Base As
(
    Select
          *
        , ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By ID Order By StartDate) RowNum
    From
        @OptionPeriods
)
Select
      B1.*
    , IsNull(B2.StartDate - 1, B1.EndDate) As NewEndDate
    , Case B1.RowNum When 1 then Null Else B1.StartDate End As NewEffectiveDate
From
    Base B1
Left Join
    Base B2
On
    B1.ID = B2.ID
    AND
    B1.RowNum + 1 = B2.RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

I am an oracle person, here is the oracle version of SQL....
You please substitute relevant analytic SQL with equivalent SQL-Server SQL...

```
SELECT id, 
       startdate,
       enddate,
       case WHEN enddate < effectivedate THEN null ELSE effectivedate end AS effectivedate
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
           startdate,
           nvl2(next_startdate,(next_startdate-1),enddate) enddate,
           effectivedate
    FROM (
        SELECT a.*,
               lead(startdate,1) over (partition by id order by id,startdate) next_startdate
        FROM tblTest a
        ORDER BY 1,2
    )
);
```

Thanks,
Venkat